# Maven and EJB3 - controlling the name of the client

Tags: java, maven, ejb-3.0

I am working on a project that has an EJB-module. There has been a problem with this module not getting into our maven-repository (Nexus), due to the fact that it lacks version numbering. I am currently trying to fix this, but I can't seem to get it the way I want it to.

In the pom.xml of the EJB-project:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <ejbVersion>3.0</ejbVersion>
      <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes </outputDirectory>
      <jarName>MyProjectEJB</jarName>
      <generateClient>true</generateClient>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

This is the way it originally was. Building the module resulted in two .jar files: MyProjectEJB.jar and MyProjectEJB-client.jar. I've tried the following to add version numbering:

```
    <jarName>MyProjectEJB-${project.version}<jarName>
```

Now, I get something like: MyProjectEJB-4.1-SNAPSHOT.jar and MyProjectEJB-4.1-SNAPSHOT-client.jar. This is almost correct, but I would really like the version number to be last in the client as well (so MyProjectEJB-client-4.1-SNAPSHOT).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`client` is in this case a Maven Classifier.

> The classifier allows to distinguish artifacts that were built from the same POM but differ in their content. It is some optional and arbitrary string that - if present - is appended to the artifact name **just after the version number**.

If you move it around in the name then it will not be possible to have correct dependencies on it.

The following dependency will use the EJB:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>your.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyProjectEJB</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The following dependency will use the EJB client:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>your.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyProjectEJB</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <classifier>client</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Comment: But the artifactId is different from the name of the jarfile, isn't it possible to control just the name of the generated jar, and keep the artifact information as is?

Comment: Well in this case you are not controlling the creation of the client library. The `maven-ejb-plugin` puts the client classifier at the end and there is not much you can do about it.

Comment: Ok, I will try a release build and see if it will be added to Nexus, that's the most important thing anyways..